# How to select the images as base image thumbnail image in bulk?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, magento-community

I have imported 7000 products through an Oscommerce website everything is great except that the imported images are not selected as base image , small image and thumbnail image.

I need to inform you that every product have a single image which will act as base image , small image and thumbnail image.

I am not getting how to do that as it's not possible for me to go to every product and mark the image as base image , small image and thumbnail image.

I have created a script and trying to run it is not giving any error but still not solving the issue.

```
<?php

 require 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();
 $prod_id = 7068 ;
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);
 $prod_img_col = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();

 foreach($prod_img_col as $gallery_img) {

  $_product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product'. $gallery_img['file'], array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false); 

 }

  ?>
```

I hope anyone knows how to do this.

Thanks,
Sarvagya

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable with editing the database directly, I can point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity cpe
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev ON cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN eav_attribute ea ON ea.attribute_id = cpev.attribute_id
WHERE ea.attribute_code = 'image' OR
      ea.attribute_code = 'small_image' OR
      ea.attribute_code = 'thumbnail'
ORDER BY sku;
```

That'll get you all of your products and all of their image attributes. Take note of which attribute has your values. You may need to look at `catalog_product_entity_varchar` directly to get the `attribute_id` of the other two image attributes (one of `image`, `small_image` or `thumbnail`, probably the latter two).

So you could write a PHP script that directly inserts into `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, using the results from the select statement above.

Comment: Hello andyjv, I tried the command it provides me the informations regarding the images but how should i insert the value my attributes for images are 85,86,87 . Thanks for your help

Comment: You could write a PHP script, but I'm sure there are other ways.

In PHP you'd get all the results into an array, grab the value of whichever attribute actually has the image, and then update `catalog_product_entity_varchar`. Thats really kind of a whole other how-to though.